# Binding nexus credentials to maven deploy job in jenkins build

Tags: maven, jenkins, credentials, maven-deploy-plugin

I have a maven pom project with defined `distributionManagement` section in `pom.xml`

```xml
<project>
...
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>my-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus.my.local/repository/my-private</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

in the `settings.xml` file I have set up the `servers` section

```xml
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-repo</id>
      <username>${env.CI_DEPLOY_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

in jenkins, I binded the credentials to these variables
[image]
But doing `mvn clean deploy` gives me following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project XY:
Failed to deploy artifacts:
Could not transfer artifact XY:pom:1.0.0 from/to my-repo (http://nexus.my.local/repository/my-private):
Failed to transfer file: http://nexus.my.local/repository/my-private/XY-1.0.0.pom.
Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
```

When I echoed the variable `${CI_DEPLOY_USERNAME}` in shell before build, it gave me `****` output -> I think that is ok.
Where else should I provide the variables? Is my project's `settings.xml` get used in maven deploy command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using environment variables as properties in Maven requires that they're prefixed with `env.`, so it should be:

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>my-repo</id>
      <username>${env.CI_DEPLOY_USERNAME}</username>
      <password>${env.CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

**Reference**:

http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties

Comment: Did you modify `settings.xml` for the Jenkins user?  Can you SSH into the Jenkins agent and run `mvn` manually, as a test?

Comment: no, I modified it in my project settings.xml, will try the ssh

Comment: well my `settings.xml` had inline commentary and this caused not to be picked up by maven command :( thank you for help

Comment: I'm glad you figured out your issue.